# PS .Contains() method does not work on Get-Content return object

Tags: powershell

I tried to use the `.Contains()` method to check if a file contains a certain string:

```
# $file content: 123
$content = Get-Content -Path $file

$content.Contains("1") # Is always false, why?
"$content".Contains("1") # Works
```

Why are the `"` required so that the .Contains method works?

```
$content | Get-Member


   TypeName: System.String

Name             MemberType            Definition                                                                                       
----             ----------            ----------                                                                                       
(...)
Contains         Method                bool Contains(string value)
```

Comment: `Get-Content` returns an **array** of lines. In your case you would want the complete content including Newlines. Use `Get-Content -Raw` to recieve a single multilined string. Then no need for the quotes which will stich the array back into a single string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commented, using `Get-Content` returns an **array** of lines.
By quoting that result `"$content"` PowerShell merges these single lines together into a single string and then the String's method `.Contains()` works as expected.

If you add switch `-Raw` to the Get-Content statement, the result is a single multiline string on which the `.Contains()` method works.

Comment: Thanks that works. I'm just wondering now why `$content.Replace("1", "0") | Set-Content -Path $file` afterwards, adds an additional new line when using `-Raw`.

Comment: @FireEmerald That extra newline is the default behavior of `Set-Content`. You can override that with switch `-NoNewline`: `Set-Content -Path $file -NoNewline`

Comment: Always these magic default behaviors in MS stuff, thanks the trailing new line is gone.

Comment: @FireEmerald Yep.. there's always some catch, but luckily also always a way out.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't pass `-raw` parameter to `Get-Content` cmdlet, the content is **returned as an array** of newline-delimited strings.